# Python multiprocessing for shared memory with an array of lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I need to know if there is a way to share memory for an array of bool lists:

```
s = Array( 'x' , range(10000000))
```

What do I have to write instead of x to make it an array of lists whose size is 64. Then I have to manipulate "s" in two different processes like these:

```
#First

for i in range(0,photoCount):
    db.newDBS.insert_one({ 'photo' : s[i], 'user_id' : ids[i] })

#Second

s[photoCount].append = inPhoto
```

What should be the type? Any help or suggestion appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `Multiprocessing` module allows 2 types of shared variables : `Array`, which is a simple 1D array of a single dtype, and `Value`, which is just a single value.

You can design your own shared variables using ctype, if you know your way in C : see the [documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects)

If you just need a 2D Array and you don't want to use ctype shared objects, maybe you could flatten your array in a single list and use `multiprocessing.Array` instead? Then just reshape when your processing is done.